# Does this use of whether make sense?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar

Does the use of "whether" make sense in this sentence?

> For instance, the use of line designs in the background imparts the
>   notion of constant motion, whether that motion be simply the air.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a proofreading service or a writers workshop, though we can help you with *specific* questions about grammar or usage. Why do you think it does or doesn't make sense? Where have you looked for this construction elsewhere? Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [hel[ center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how this site operates.

Comment: If you substitute *even if that motion is* for *whether that motion be*, you get a grammatical English sentence. Whether that sentence means what you want this one to is another question.

Answer (score 1):

No – the sentence is incomplete. The current use of the word "whether" implies there is a potential alternative cause of the motion other than the air. It's hard to offer a suggestion of how you might rewrite the sentence without more context.